# How to add sharePoint Online List with ASp.NET MVC Form to store data instead of using any SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I am new in Office 365 SharePoint online.

I know ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework. Now I want to develop a web application using ASP.Net MVC where I want to use SharePoint Online List to Insert/Delete/Update/View (CRUD Operations) my form data or others data instead of MS Server or other external database sources.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint REST API to select, insert, update and delete data in SharePoint lists. The biggest challenge is not the "CRUD", it's the credentials. You can find many blog articles on the web on using the REST API in 365.

Here's a few resources on the REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

One with an Office 365 focus:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online