# Entity Framework Core with SharePoint Lists?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

Is it possible to connect Entity Framework Core to SharePoint lists?

Instead of having database tables, I would like to have SharePoint lists. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196050/how-to-add-sharepoint-online-list-with-asp-net-mvc-form-to-store-data-instead-of) can help u.